# Turret size damage ratio?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

I've got *Fusion Beam Emitter*, and I'm thinking which ships should I select for the most DPS.

What is a damage ratio of each turret size - small, medium, large, huge?

Answer (score 1):

Each turret size offers progressivelly less gain in damage output over previous:

Small   base damage
Medium  1.5 x base damage
Large   2.25 x base damage
Huge    3.37.5 x base damage

So in late game you get access to double and triple mount modules for turrets that allow you to swap one huge turret with 3 medium ones, allowing you to trade range and some reactor efficiency for greater damage.